# Can I include reCAPTCHA in a Windows application instead of in a webpage?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, recaptcha

I'd like to integrate it into a Windows application. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and it is a C# Windows Forms application.

Comment: Why would you need this? Bots would have hard time using your Windows Forms Application which is what a Captcha is trying to prevent.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov How about having a login page which sends a request to API and you want to protect an API with gcaptcha ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    public static Image DownloadReCaptcha(string key, ref string challenge)
    {

        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string response = client.DownloadString(string.Format("http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k={0}", key));

            Match match = Regex.Match(response, "challenge : '(.+?)'");

            if (match.Captures.Count == 0)
            {
                challenge = null;
                return null;
            }

            challenge = match.Groups[1].Value;
            if (File.Exists("captcha.jpg")) File.Delete("captcha.jpg");
            client.DownloadFile(string.Format("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c={0}", challenge),
                                "captcha.jpg");
            return Image.FromFile("captcha.jpg");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            challenge = null;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Use it like :

```
string challenge = null; // you will need this to submit captcha answer
pictureBox1.Image = DownloadReCaptcha("reCaptcha site key", ref challenge);
```

### How to find the key ?

In the HTML source of web-page you will find something like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LexLsMSAAAAABUuI6bvUYfxaumgcu0vGiEFotDA"></script>`

`key = 6LexLsMSAAAAABUuI6bvUYfxaumgcu0vGiEFotDA`

Comment: What format is the key variable supposed to be in? I'm not familiar with reCAPTCHA.

Comment: Should I just always use this key? Update: The challenge variable returns random letters and numbers... Isn't this string supposed to contain the correct answer to the challenge? Is this an encryption key or something?

Comment: you can or cannot, depends on u, using the key & above function will make things easier!

Comment: I read the comment in the code and it says I need the challenge to check the answer, but how can I check the answer?

Comment: that entirely depends on ur website for which u need to submit captcha! different websites responds diff way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24531/discussion-between-appdeveloper-and-phoenix-logan)

Comment: `public static Image` `return false;` it wont even compile

Comment: @DeX3r - thnx, fixed, i copied it my my own project that returned boolean & captcha was solved using antigate